Add UserAgent info to flask log
How to add UserAgent to Flask requests log shown in console?
backend-flask |  * Serving Flask app 'generate-ics'
backend-flask |  * Debug mode: off
backend-flask | WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
backend-flask |  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
backend-flask |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8081
backend-flask |  * Running on http://172.28.0.2:8081
backend-flask | Press CTRL+C to quit
backend-flask | 64.227.xx.xx - - [08/Nov/2024 18:55:44] "GET /rentaldb.ics HTTP/1.1" 200 -
backend-flask | 62.113.xx.xx - - [08/Nov/2024 18:55:46] "GET /rentaldb.ics HTTP/1.1" 200 -
backend-flask | 64.227.xx.xx - - [08/Nov/2024 18:55:49] "GET /rentaldb.ics HTTP/1.1" 200 -
                               ^
                  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0


Looks like you can use the Flask logger blog post. To grab the user agent looks like you can get that using the werkzeug module

To alter the default logs you will have to extend the existing werkzeug implementations.
The relevant implementations can be found in the following link:
https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/src/werkzeug/serving.py
This logging happens through these methods:

send_response calls log_request
log_request calls log
log writes to the Werkzeug logger

To add the User-Agent, you will have to:

create a CustomRequestHandler class extending WSGIRequestHandler.
override log_request to add User-Agent to the log message
override log to properly handle the message formatting
configure Flask to use our custom handler

Example code that achieves it:
import logging
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.serving import WSGIRequestHandler

class CustomRequestHandler(WSGIRequestHandler):
    def log(self, type, message, *args):
        logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
        getattr(logger, type)(message)

    def log_request(self, code='-', size='-'):
        user_agent = self.headers.get('User-Agent', 'Unknown')
        log_message = f'{self.address_string()} - {user_agent} - [{self.log_date_time_string()}] "{self.requestline}" {code} {size}'
        self.log('info', log_message)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, request_handler=CustomRequestHandler)


